# jQuery not generating my JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, global-variables

I am trying to generate a JSON document from a form. The output I want would look something like this:

```
{
    "name": "joe-pc",
    "device_type": "server",
    "os": "windows",
    "info": [
        {
            "net_info": [
                {
                    "ip": "192.168.0.5",
                    "name": "eth0"
                },
                {
                    "ip": "192.168.0.28",
                    "name": "eth1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "OS_info": [
                {
                    "name": "windows"
                },
                {
                    "build": "123.1.3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "whatever_info": [
                {}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm getting is:

```
{"info":[{}]}
```

Code Snips:

```
$('#top_three_next').click(function (e) {
        var json_obj = new Object();
        json_obj.name = $('#name').val(); //manditory
        json_obj.device_type = $('#device_type').val(); //manditory
        json_obj.os = $('#os').val(); //not a manditory field
        // is this not available outside the function? 
        // even if I declare json_obj as a global var?
    });
```

Full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/jdell64/Tu9bB/  (start at line 93 in the js pane).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your code on jsfiddle looks a bit messy :)

I see

```
var json_obj = new Object();
```

declaration on line 95. This Line is not needed at all. Because you already defined empty json_obj at the beginning of your JS. And this declaration overheads global variable & uses local variable from callback scope & all data filled in it is missing after callback ends. If you remove that line you'll get the following structure at the end.

```
{"name":"1","device_type":"2","os":"3","info":[{}]}
```

EDITED:
Also lines 191-192 is totally unclear for me:

```
infoList.push(infoDocs);
json_obj.info = infoList;
```

Both `infoDocs` & `infoList` variables is not defined in event handler function, but they also not defined globally!

Comment: Yes, at least one issue is going to be that hiding of the global. To use the global, remove the "var" in front of json_obj inside the click function.

Comment: Sorry about the messy code. I'm not a full-time coder yet and I don't know a lot of conventions. Thank you for your help though, and I would love input on how to improve my code (if you want): https://github.com/jdell64/IPACS